# How to store a keypair and use it in other classes for decryption?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, key-pair

I'm trying to encrypt String values that are getting send to `@PostMapping` method in `@RestController` via postman and store them in the database.

This is my code for encrypting the Strings

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);

        keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();           

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");


        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());

        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(this.toBeEncrypted.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

and then i store this `encrypted` variable to the database.

I have another class that decrypts the string that is stored in the database, but it doesn't decrypt the encrypted value, and I know that is because it doesn't have the right key to do it.

I tried making the `KeyPair` a static variable so both of my custom classes, `StringEncryptor` and `StringDecryptor` use the same object of keypair but that stops working properly when the server restarts, so I believe when the server restarts, the static KeyPair object which I used to encrypt/decrypt gets reinitialized so that's not the key which locked the String variable.

I'm not sure but I kind of think I should store the key that I locked the String objects with, so I can use it again later in other classes to unlock the encrypted Strings.

most of the tutorials on the internet are about cipher algorithm and others decrypt the encrypt the file in the same method which is totally useless in real-world projects and that's not what I'm looking for.

I need to know how to store and where to store and how to retrieve these keys back again for decrypting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason, you are using asymmetric encryption? From what I read it is the same application that does the en-/decryption. For these scenarios a symmetric cypher, e.g., `AES` is better suited.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, thank you for mentioning symmetric, I switched to AES and it's cool now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key management is a whole topic onto itself. You've already discovered, I hope, that keeping keys in RAM is not an option.

Commonly you would try and put the key in a key store. This key store may be backed by hardware. In that case the actual private key operations also need to take place in hardware, or you'd have to take out the key. In the simplest form the key can simply be retrieved from a *password protected* key store (which would mean a PKCS#12 compatible file for latest versions of Java). Now you can store keys, but the problem is that you'd have to enter the password on restarts.

Furthermore, generally Java `KeyStore` implementations also require a certificate to be present with the private key, so you'd have to generate or request a certificate for your private key. There are many tutorials on how to create a self signed certificate from a key pair. This is because Java relies heavily on PKIX, the public key infrastructure according to the US ANS(I) standards, which all start with the letter X (such as X.509 which defines what common TLS / CMS certificates look like).

OK, so now you know what direction you should look at, I'm afraid that you'll have to do some research from here on on how to manage your keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, At first, i didn't quite understand it, but after some researches, it makes sense to me.
can you please tell me more about certificates? like what I should I pass to Keystore beside the privateKey as Certificate[]? how many certificates in a certificate array should I pass to the PrivateKeyEntry constructor? what should those certificates contain? thanks in advance

Comment: You should pass a chain of certificates, where the certs are signed by the private key of the parent certificate, up to the leaf certificate that holds your private key. That leaf certificate should have a key usage for encryption as that's your purpose. You can also use a *self signed* certificate, in which case your certificate should also be valid for signing certificates, of course. There are numerous ways of generating PKCS#12 key stores using OpenSSL which you can then use in Java. That's probably more easy than generating it using Java or the `keytool` command in the JDK.

Comment: All the other information is really up to you - they are essentially your details. Name, expiry date etc.